# Deploying WAR to multiple Tomcat instances

Tags: tomcat, deployment, apache2, war

I'm wondering if anyone can point me to some links and/or scripts that deal with deploying a web application to multiple Tomcat instances without much disruption in service.

Currently we have an F5 Load Balancer between 2 Apache servers and the app requests are proxy'd through to tomcat using mod_proxy.  Pretty standard stuff.  When I need to redeploy the latest changes, I create the WAR file and then SCP it to both web servers.  I shut one tomcat instance down, throw the new war out there, start it back up.  Then do the same for the other server.

I'm looking for something a bit more automated than this process.  Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I've stumbled on this [jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin).  Would this be a good approach?  And FYI, I'm not using Maven.  I'm not opposed to a possible Gradle solution, however.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Why don't you just put all of the commands you're issuing into a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://blog.kwatee.net/2011/05/deploy-web-application-on-multiple.html
There's a REST API that let's you script it for your specific automation needs.